# Use LatLng from autocomplete to find nearby place using vue-googlemaps

Tags: google-maps, vue.js, maps, vuex

I have a autocomplete component on my landing page where I capture user address details (latitude, longitude, address etc.)

I commit these details to the store:

```
  locate ({commit}, payload) {
    commit('setLong', payload.long);
    commit('setLat' , payload.lat);
    commit('setAddress', payload.address);
  }
```

The user is then directed to the next page (component) where some nearby places are shown from the address that was just entered.

I'm using the vue-googlemaps npm package which requires you to set the default center data (which is basically the default LatLng):

Template:

```
<googlemaps-map
  class="map"
  :center.sync="center"
  :zoom="12"
>
```

Script:

```
data: function () {
  return {
   center: {
     lat: 48.8566,
     lng: 2.352
   },
  }
}
```

I'm using Vuex to get my data from the store:

```
...mapGetters([
    'address',
    'lng',
    'lat'
]),
```

And then setting those values to the return data as shown above:

```
data: function () {
  return {
   center: {
     lat: this.lat,
     lng: this.lng
   },
  }
}
```

This does not seem to be working at all - I'm getting multiple errors and I'm assuming it's because the data I'm retrieving from the store is not available before the nearby place component loads.

I've been bashing my head over this issue, some help would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check to render map only when `lat` and `lng` available using `v-if`

```
<googlemaps-map
  class="map"
  :center.sync="center"
  :zoom="12"
  v-if="this.lat && this.lng"
>
...
...
data() {
  return {}
},
computed: {
  center() {
    return {
      lat: this.lat,
      lng: this.lng
    }
  }
}
```

Further more, you can change `center` to computed property to make it reactive.